# Uploading a file to an ASPX server-side page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble understanding how to send an uploaded file's content to my ASPX server-side. This is for an HTML-4 implementation where File API isn't available on the client-side, and using .NET v4.0.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML on FileReceiver.aspx:

```
<input type="button" id="uploadFile" value="Upload" /> 
<div class="hidden">
    <form id="uploadFileForm">
        <input type="file" id="browseForFiles" />
    </form>
</div>
```

(client-side) JS:

```
$("#uploadFile").click(function () {
    $("#browseForFiles").click();
});

$("#browseForFiles").change(function () {
    $("#uploadFileForm").submit();
});

$("#uploadFileForm").submit(function (e) {

    // prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // send file to server
    $.ajax({
        url: "FileReceiver.aspx/ReceiveFile",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "multipart/form-data", // <---- is this right?
        data: ???, // <-------------------------- what goes here? 
        success: function(data) { 
            // do something on success 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

(Server-side) FileReceiver.aspx.cs:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ReceiveFile(??? receivedFile) // <-- what type goes here?
{
    // do something and return status
}
```

Please help fill in the two "???" in the codes above. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$("#uploadFileForm").submit(function (e) {

    // prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($('#uploadFileForm')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "FileReceiver.aspx/ReceiveFile",
        type: "POST",
        // Form data
        data: formData, // <-- see above to see where this comes from
        dataType: "json", // <-- the dataType you're RETURNING, not sending
        cache: false,
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) { 
            // do something on success 
        } 
    });
});
```

Then your C# code should look like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ReceiveFile(HttpPostedFileBase receivedFile) 
{
    // do something and return status
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the super-fast response. Let me try this and get back to you! :)

Comment: No problem, had to solve the same issue myself recently

Comment: 'FormData' is not supported in IE :(

Comment: You know, that would explain an issue I've been having with IE lately! Ok, now I'm committed. I want a solution too!

Comment: I did find a hack though -- [this link](http://kaushikghosh12.blogspot.in/2014/02/ajax-fileupload-on-all-browsers.html) outlines your exact answer, and explains what is to be done in IE. I will check this out and let you know. Meanwhile you could try it too!